# How to add audio files in iOS static library

Tags: ios, static-libraries

I am building a static library. Now, I want to play an audio file when a push is received, like a ringtone. Tone should not be system notification tone. How do I do this? From app, I am able to do this but in static library, how do I include the file. I don't want to let my client know which is being played.

Comment: not possible to add a audio file in static library. You need to create a resource file externally where you can add the audio file and you need to add this in the project  along with your library and then you need to communicate with it.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible to add a audio file in static library. You need to create a resource file externally where you can add the audio file and you need to add this in the project  along with your library and then you need to communicate with it. i had same situation for image i used base64 string of that image and used, if you can change the audio file to base64 it is better